# Show that there doesn't exist a larger square in the coordinate plane

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation

**Question**: [image]

**Solution**:[image]

At one point in the solution, EFGH is assumed to have a specific coordinate without loss of generality (WLOG) but does that hold? I think we can't assume it WLOG. If we define different coordinate points for EFGH, do we not get a flaw in the next set of statements ("So ABCD has side length less than $1$. But $A,B,C,D$ must have $\cdots$ this gives us a contradiction")? Like, we are already defining the smallest coordinate possible for the larger square as asked in the question. We can define ABCD by that coordinate WLOG, but not EFGH I think.

Irrespective of whether it holds true or not and whether there's or there's no fallacy, please explain the same.

Comment: You need to be patient! The WOLOG here is probably OK, since you can always scale your grid. So another approach is: "Let's call the side length of EFGH one unit". Then they claim that it's not possible to produce a square with side length less than one unit, which is equivalent to the claim by the reversibility of operations.

Comment: @dbx yes, but isn't EFGH supposed to be bigger than ABCD? Like if we assume the bigger sqaure to be of the smallest possible size, we can't get ABCD right?

Comment: the WLOG isn't phrased in the best way possible here, but it does work. What needs to be said is that the grid can be rotated and/or dilated/stretched by an arbitrary factor (another point of view is that you are switching to a different set of coordinates). The key thing is that the result of the operations is invariant under such rotation and/or rescaling, so the sequence of operations produces the same sequence of configurations, regardless of what set of coordinates are used to label the points.